# What does the Dark Cloud rune do?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

The [Rain of Vengeance](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/rain-of-vengeance) tooltips are not very clear regarding the effects of the various runes.

The Dark Cloud tooltip shows a decrease in the damage, but what else does it do? Does it increase the number of arrows dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It extends the effect to 12 seconds:

> Launch a massive volley of guided arrows that rain down on enemies for
>   34% weapon damage for 12 seconds.

Comment: I shouldn't read too fast the tooltips, I'm missing out half of the content... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Kappei No problem... probably just too tired from playing "too much" Diablo 3 or not enough time to read the tool tip in between slaughtering the minions of hell :)